# R function to inspect number of arguments in another function?

Tags: r, function

Is there a built-in R function, or a way to write an R function, that can check how many inputs another function takes, and also lists names of optional arguments.

Let's call this desired function, f, then the following command:

```
f(dnorm)
```

should output

```
4
```

and

```
mean, sd, log
```

Since there are 4 arguments associated with 'dnorm' and and 3 optional arguments: mean, sd, log.

Or maybe this is not possible? Any insight is appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try:

```
length(formals(dnorm))
# [1] 4
names(Filter(function(x) !is.symbol(x) || nchar(as.character(x)), formals(dnorm)))
# [1] "mean" "sd"   "log"
```

Two functions technically, but gets the job done.  For the second one, you may need to play around a bit if the default arguments are complex.

Comment: Wow, exactly what I was looking for! I have to wait 9 more mins before accepting... :)

Comment: @kyphos, glad this helped.  Do keep in mind my warning about complex default arguments.  For example, if a default argument is a vector with multiple values, you'll get warnings with this.  The key thing to know is that non-default arguments are zero length symbols (hence the `nchar(as.character(x))` which returns 0 for those).

Comment: @kyphos, Also, if you're embedding this someplace, you should probably do `is.symbol(x)` do guard against the possibility that a default argument is actually "".

Comment: Thanks, will keep that in mind, right now I intend to use this with the 'Curry' function in the 'functional' package to automatically generate some functions.

Comment: @kyphos, great.  I wish `functional` were part of base.